# Sufficient conditions for square map to be group isomorphism, with basic tools

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let G be a finite abelian group. I am asked to find sufficient conditions for
$$ \begin{array}{cccc} 
\alpha: & G & \rightarrow & G & \\
& g & \mapsto & g^{2}
\end{array} $$
to be a group isomorphism.

I already know that if the order of the group is odd, then $ \alpha $ is injective, and thus bijective.

Is there any way to prove this without using cyclic groups and Lagrange's Theorem?

I am supposed to use just basic things like definitions and equivalence relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to prove that $g\mapsto g^2$ is not an isomorphism for even cardinality finite groups directly from the group axioms is to consider the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$. This has order $2$, and if $|G|$ is even, must have an even number of fixed points, since points are either fixed or in a pair, since this map is order $2$. But we know the identity is a fixed element, so there must be a non-identity element fixed by this, that is, some nontrivial $g\in G$ such that $g^{-1}=g$. For this $g$, we have $g^2=e=e^2$, so the map can't be injective if the order of $G$ is even. Note, we didn't need $G$ to be abelian for this argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can one conclude then? Because the proof in your answer tell that if the order of $ G $ is even, $ \alpha  $ can't be injective.

Comment: So I thought you've already worked out that if the order is odd, then the map is bijective, this is just for getting the even case out of the way. If you're looking for a stripped down version of the odd argument, you can use abelian-ness to show that is the map isn't injective, then $g^2=e$ for some nonidentity $g$, then use that multiplication by $g$ on the left is an order two map without fixed points, so the group must be even. (This really is Lagranges theorem in disguise).

Comment: Wonderful! I apologize because my question wasn't clear enough, and I thank you again.